# Is there a command that will allow a user to "type" from the command line?

Tags: c, command-line

I have been exploring the system(""); command in C. It seems that it directly does what a GUI can do from the contexts of a program, except for actually "typing". Is there a command line keyword that will "type"? For example, you use system("notepad.exe"), which will open a blank notepad, with the cursor blinking eagerly for input. I was wanting to "type" into this blank notepad *through* the command line.  I've played around with things like 'system("print abcde");' , 'system("type abcde");' and I cannot find any command that will do what I want in my searching. Does such functionality exist in the Windows command prompt?

Let me try to demonstrate what I am trying to do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
system("dir");
system("notepad.exe");
system(/*This is where I need to put the code that will type to notepad */);
return 0;
}
```

I just want a baby program that can automate printing to notepad basically.

Comment: Please don't comment to yourself. :) You can [edit] your question and add that information there if you think it's important. If you don't think it's worth the effort, it's probably not worth adding as a comment.

Comment: You could execute a command that would write something to file and then have notepad open that file.

Comment: Why ever bother having notepad open it? What are you going to do with it once you have a text file in notepad, other than save it? Just bypass notepad altogether, and have your program write a text file to disk. Or, if you wanted to hard code the text in the first place, just don't use C, type it into notepad and go to `File->Save`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might have to use WIN32 API for this, you can Get a handle on the notepad, and send the input from the console, to the notepad window using `SendMessage()` to the notepad's handle.

Comment: Thank you Aniket, how would that be implemented in the code I posted?

Comment: Possibly beyond the scope of your question.  Have you ever done Win32 API coding before?

Comment: it won't go into `system()` function. Its a whole new ballgame of Win32 programming you might have to master.

Comment: No I have not. I'm afraid I'm just a novice at programming in C. I really am enjoying the power of being able to do FUN things with my programs with this 'system()' command in C. I really want to be able to write code that can type into processors and *autopilot* the navigation of GUIs and data entry with my code. Like to open a browser, with system("firefox.exe") and then 'type' into the search bar with my own code. Is what I'm wanting to do beyond my current scope?

Comment: @SmithWillSuffice if you're a novice, then it would be a bad idea to do it in C. Try AUTOIT to automate your GUIs. Its great, I like AutoIT

Comment: Thank you Aniket. Its not the answer I wanted to hear, but if its the truth you've saved me knocking my head against the wall trying. You seem to see my aim, and I seen your profile: I do believe you know what you're talking about. Thanks for your time and for saving me a dead end: for now at least.

Comment: That's cool, thanks for accepting the answer. But do try AutoIT, it is designed specifically for automating GUIs.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for!  Awesome, you made my night. Pity StackOverflow lacks the capacity to network with users. If this were Facebook you'd have just received a friend request :)  I can't wait to explore this AutoIT!